# PlasticSCM repo do-over

Tags: version-control, plasticscm

What is the best way to start a PlasticSCM repo completely over from the beginning, but keep the same repo name? I am using Plastic Distributed Version Control and so far no other collaborators are using the repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean a fresh start you can simply delete the repository and create a new one with the same name.
If you are concerned about Plastic SCM backup files, you don't have to worry about it, Plastic indeed doesn't like deleting stuff too fast so they keep a backup version (Which is also delete-able by admin/server owner). Creating a new repository with the same name will not affect the backup and will let you start a fresh repository with the same name.

Copied from Plastic SCM guide:
You can remove/archive a repository via command:

```
    cm removerepository myproject@host:port
```

Note: the removerepository command does not delete the database in the database backend.

The repository database in the physical database backend name follows this pattern:

`rep_xx.plastic`
The file for myproject repository, in the previous sample, will be

`rep_3.plastic`

You can locate the database with the name in your database backend and back it up using the tool of your choice. After you have backed it up, you can delete the database from your backend if desired.

Reference:
[plastic-scm-version-control-administrator-guide](https://www.plasticscm.com/documentation/administration/plastic-scm-version-control-administrator-guide)